# STL compilation error when defining iterator within template class

Tags: c++, stl

The code below gives the error:

> `error: type ‘std::list<T,std::allocator<_Tp1> >’ is not derived from type ‘Foo<T>’`
>   `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘iter’`

```
#include <list>

template <class T> class Foo 
{
  public:
      std::list<T>::iterator iter;

  private:
      std::list<T> elements;
};
```

Why and what should this be to be correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `typename std::list<T>::iterator`. This is because `list` depends on the template parameter, so the compiler cannot know what exactly is the name `iterator` within it going to be (well, technically it could know, but the C++ standard doesn't work that way). The keyword `typename` tells the compiler that what follows is a name of a type.

Comment: I still don't get why this is so. For example, why don't we need to use 'typename std::list<T> elements'?

Comment: @Agnel: Because then we won't be trying to access names defined within a template class.

Answer (score 3):

You need a typename

```
template <class T> class Foo  {
    public:
        typename std::list<T>::iterator iter;

    private:
        std::list<T> elements;
};
```