# STL Error Converting VS 6 Project to VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

I'm converting a Visual Studio 6 project to Visual Studio 2010. The project uses STL heavily.
After converting, the compiler gives an error. The code and error are as follows.

```
#include <list>

namespace mySpace
{

template <class T>
class MyList : public std::list<T>
{
    public:
        typedef std::list<T>::allocator_type AllocatorType;
    }
```

Error: 
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'AllocatorType'   c:\myProject\mylist.h   39  1

I can click on the 'allocator_type' text and hit F12 and the IDE takes me to the 'allocator_type' definition in list.

If I remove '::allocator_type' the error goes away.

Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: This should be a Visual Studio achievement.  I wouldn't want to unlock that one, good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [STL compilation error when defining iterator within template class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242821/stl-compilation-error-when-defining-iterator-within-template-class)

Comment: @BoPersson: it's the same deal, but that one is about iterators and this one is about allocators :)

Comment: I tried adding the typename, and that worked. The really weird part is this: I realized that this code is in the context of std::list<T>, so it shouldn't need that prefix. I removed the prefix and the typename and it now compiles. The new code looks like this: typedef allocator_type AllocatorType;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
typedef typename std::list<T>::allocator_type AllocatorType;
```

You have to tell the compiler allocator_type is actually a type.

By the way, inheriting from STL containers isn't a great practice as they don't have virtual destructors.

Comment: Wow, interesting, no virtual destructors... We inherited all of this code. I really wouldn't have written it this way.

Comment: Why do I have to tell the compiler that std::list<T>::allocator_type is a type, but I don't have to tell the compiler that allocator type is a type if I strip off the std::list<T>::. I changed the code to this: typedef allocator_type AllocatorType; and it compiles

Comment: This is starting to make more sense to me. It appears that the std::list<T>::allocator syntax confuses the compiler at times and the typename is just a way to clarify this for complex cases that confuse the compiler.

Comment: Re inheriting from containers, it's going to work ok as long as you don't add any data members in your derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the typedef line as:

```
typedef typename std::list<T>::allocator_type AllocatorType;
```

to state that `std::list<T>::allocator`is a type.