# Subclassed STL list<T>::reference Compile Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, list, stl

I'm converting a project from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2010. The project heavily uses STL. There is a custom class that subclasses list to add more methods to it. Following is the code and compiler error that I'm getting.

```
    #include <list> 
    namespace mySpace 
    { 
    template <class T> 
    class MyList : public std::list<T> 
    { 
        ...
    };

    template <class T>
    MyList<T>::reference MyList<T>::find(const_reference p_constreferenceItem) const
    {
     return std::find(this->begin(), this->end(), p_constreferenceItem);
    }
   } // namespace mySpace
```

Error:

```
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'MySpace::MyList<T>::find'   c:\myproject\mylist.h   300 1
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\myproject\mylist.h   300 1   
Error   4   error C2888: 'MyList<T>::reference reference' : symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'MySpace' c:\myproject\mylist.h   300 1
```

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're just missing a `typename` in front of `MyList<T>::reference`, since it's a dependent type (one that depends on the type of `T`) and the compiler doesn't know that `MyList<T>::reference` is a type and assumes by default that it's a variable name:

```
template <class T>
typename MyList<T>::reference MyList<T>::find(
                              const_reference p_constreferenceItem) const
```

You don't need this for the `const_reference` though, as the compiler is in `MyList<T>`'s scope as soon as he's seen the `::` (that of the method name) and now knows that `const_reference` names a type. In the same way you don't need to use `typename` when you're already inside the `MyList<T>`'s scope, e.g. when declaring or inline-defining the method inside the class definition.

I'm not sure why VC6 allowed this, though. But we all know that VC6 and templates aren't that big friends, not to speak of the loose specification of C++ templates and their behaviour at that time.

disclaimer: Sorry to the language lawyers if the terminology used here is a bit informal.

Comment: I've also just seen that this is the same error like in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9524421/743214), so reading (and [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) for) your existing questions would be a starting point.

Comment: templates have always been confusing to me. I didn't expect that typename had to go in the return type in this case. In the first question there was a typedef which I could see why the typename had to go there. It must be that the typename keys the compiler that the following syntax is a type name. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is typename needed in some places and not in others? This doesn't make much sense right now to me.

Comment: @SteveGraber Like said above, when you are inside the scope of the template class (like inside the class definition or inside the parameter list or definition body of a method) the compiler knows the class it's handling and therefore knows it members (likewise you don't need to write `MyList<T>::const_reference` in the parameter list above), so it also knows which are types and which are variables or methods or whatever...

Comment: ...but when you are not in class scope (like when using a member of a different class like in your other question, or at the return type of the method above), the compiler doesn't know anything about `MyClass<T>`'s members, not even if they're types or variables, as it's a template class and it isn't an existing type until it's instantiated (you could have a specialization for `MyClass<float>`, where `reference` is actually not a typedef but a static variable, odd but works).

Comment: Hmmm, something doesn't quite make sense still. In the first question I had, the typedefs were inside the MyList class which derived from std::list<T>. So, it seems like I wouldn't need the std::list<T>:: in the typedef. I took the std::list<T>:: out and it compiles. Then I removed the typename and it still compiles.

Comment: Looks like this now... template <class T>
class MyList : public std::list<T>
    {
    public:
        typedef allocator_type AllocatorType;